# How git merge others unknown changes

Tags: git, git-merge

**Hi everyone**

I use git for my project. After, when I had finished my code every time, I pushed(through FTP) a code to employer server(server didn't support git technology). But sometimes, some the others developers change the code on the server and save there. We didn't use an overall git repositories. How can I track a changes and merge to my repository, ifI don't know where in the files was the changes. Please, tell me a right easy way.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this question should be moved to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Without knowing the exact setup of your system, and your workflows, and finding out exactly how you can prevent developers from doing certain things, this is an almost impossible question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty easy answer. Git is a great way to version control your code, but some discipline is required for deployed code.

So start by not allowing developers to access code in the server and change it right there. Don't ask, instead simply close access.

Any code that gets deployed is only code that was checked in, built and hopefully tested.

Before you close all access, you need to compare server vs. repository to make sure you are not losing any changes.

Ask your devs to go and study continuous integration and devops, you definitively need it.